# double load function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Good evening everyone I have a question about two load function. I hope you can help me.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function () {
        $("#top_menu").load("menu.php");
        $("#content").load("content.php");
        return false;
    });
});
```

second load function doesn't work, I mean it is doesn't load content. what is wrong?

---

I need to realize double load, load menu.php to main.php and load 
content.php to menu.php

menu.php-

```
 <div id="menu">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="" id="mlink1"></li>
         <li><a href="" id="mlink2"></li>
         <li><a href="" id="mlink3"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Where is `#content` element?

Comment: can you create `jsFiddle` for your question? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: top_menu - block (<div></div>)  for menu  ;   content -block for content

Comment: Show the HTML please

Comment: if `#content` is some element that gets added to the DOM as result of the first `.load()` call, then the 2nd `.load()` statement definitely won't work...

Comment: I need to realize double load, load menu.php to main.php and load content.php to menu.php . the second load function supose to load in the block that loaded from first load function

Comment: So my question how to do it, is it any possibilities?

Comment: where is `#top_menu`?

Comment: thanks everyone who answer me, I found the solution in comment below, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load one by one...

```
$('#top_menu').load('menu.php', function() {
    $('#content').load('content.php');
});
```

More info if you read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/)